# push json value with specific category id

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, firebase

not sure whats going wrong  ..  using angularJS and firebase simply trying  to store value in json  in specific catogory

this works if I provide direct value ..

```
group.categories[2].nodes.push({
```

but if I try this .. it do not work

```
var catID = scope.$modelValue.id;

group.categories[catID].nodes.push({

TypeError: group.categories[catID] is undefined       
-> group.categories[catID].nodes = group.categories[catID].nodes  || [];
```

I tried converting catID to string and Number nothing works .. please help

Comment: What is group? Can you provide more of your code?

Comment: It looks like `catID` is refering to an element that doesn't exist. Can you set up a reproduction of your problem on jsfiddle?

Comment: problem is 
group.categories[3] = works

Comment: thanks guys .. I was matching array index with id :(